# Returning to main view controller?

Tags: iphone, swift

I am a new programmer and I have 2 view controllers and after my game is over a alert pops up with a "play again" button.

Instead of restarting the game after the timer on the 2nd view controller I want the play again to return to the first view controller that has the play button. What do I do? I have the code for the alert below :

```
   func subtractTime() {
    seconds--
    timerLabel.text = "Time: \(seconds)"

    if(seconds == 0)  {

        timer.invalidate()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Time is up!",
            message: "You scored \(count) points",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
            action in self.setupGame()
        }))
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)


    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be usually done using segue that tells the storyboard to connect to another view controller when a specified action is called

For segue, you will need to first set the segue in your story board by declaring an identifier for it. Then in your function you can call

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("segueId", sender: nil)
```

I believe you can also do right after presentViewController

```
let mainViewController = yourMainControllerName(); 
presentViewController(mainViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now, you should place either one of them in the handler after the user canceled it in alert.addAction

```
alert.addAction(action in self.setupGame() UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{(ViewController: UIViewController!) in let mainViewController: secondViewController = segue.mainViewController as secondViewController}
```